# Ayuda, Petición $http.get devuelve undefined al primer llamado?

Tags: angularjs, api, funciones

actualmente estoy trabajando en un cliente con angularjs 1.5.8, y tengo un servicio llamado AuthenticationService.

```
discovrApp.factory('AuthenticationService', function (
  $http,
  $rootScope,
  $localStorage,
  jwtHelper,
  apiURL){
  var service = {};

  var config = {headers:  {
      Authorization: '',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  };

  service.Login = Login;
  service.Logout = Logout;
  service.SignUp = SignUp;

  service.Profile = Profile;
  service.ChangePassword = ChangePassword;
  service.ResetPassword = ResetPassword;
  service.GetProfile = GetProfile;
  //service.SignUp = SignUp;
  //service.SignUp = SignUp;


  return service;

  function Login(username,password,callback) {
    $http.post(apiURL + 'api/rest/auth/login/', { username: username,   password: password })
      .success(function(response){
        //login successful if there's a token in the respose
        if(response.token){
          //decode token, to get the user id insert on payload
          var token = jwtHelper.decodeToken(response.token);
          var userProfile = 0;
          userProfile = GetProfile(token.user_id);
          console.log(userProfile);
          //store username and token in local storage to keep user logged in between paga refreshes
          $localStorage.currentUser = {id: token.user_id, username: username, token: response.token };
          //config.headers.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.token;
          //add jwt token to auth header for all requests made by the $http services
         $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.token;
          //execuete callback with true to indicate successful login
          callback(true);
        }else{
          //execute callback with false to indicate failed login
          callback(false);
        }
      });
  }

  function Logout() {
    $http.post(apiURL + 'api/rest/auth/logout/')
      .success(function(response){
        //remove user from local storage and clear http auth header
        delete $localStorage.currentUser;
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        config.headers.Authorization = '';
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
      });

  }

  function SignUp(callback,username,password1,password2,email,more){
    $http.post(apiURL + 'api/rest/auth/registration/', { username: username, password1: password1, password2: password2, email: email})
      .success(function(response){
        //login successful if there's a token in the respose
        if(response.token){
         console.log(response.token);
         //store username and token in local storage to keep user logged in between paga refreshes
          $localStorage.currentUser = { username: username, token: response.token };
          //add jwt token to auth header for all requests made by the $http services
          $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'JWT ' + response.token;
          //execuete callback with true to indicate successful login
          callback(true);
        }else{
          //execute callback with false to indicate failed login
          callback(false);
        }
      });
  }

  function Profile(){
    $http.get(apiURL + 'api/user/' + $localStorage.currentUser.id + '/').
      then(function successCallback(response) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
          console.log(response.data)
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log(response);
     });
  }

  function GetProfile(id){
    $http.get(apiURL + 'api/user/' + id + '/').
    then(function successCallback(response){
      $rootScope.userProfile = response.data.Kind;
      localStorage.setItem('profile', $rootScope.userProfile);
      //console.log(($rootScope.userProfile = response.data.Kind)); 
    });     
    return $rootScope.userProfile;
  }
});
```

El problema lo tengo con las funciones Profile() y GetProfile(), cuando las mando a llamar por primera vez siempre me devuelven o asignan "undefined", y si dejo un console.log en las funciones para imprimir el resultado de la api, primero devuelve undefined, ya si lo vuelvo a llamar, me devuelve o asigna el valor, el problema es la primera vez que la llamo siempre, siempre me devuelve undefined y la segunda vez ya no,me gustaría saber si alguno le ha pasado y sabe la razón y forma de solucionar esto.

**NOTAS: En el servicio que creo podrán notar varias cosas, y es que he probado diferentes formas como guardar los datos devueltos por la petición get en una variable local, y luego imprimir esta variable local, sin resultado positivo al primer intento.
Al refrescar la pagina, y volver a probar, me devuelve undefined a la primera y ya luego lo devuelve.

Gracias de antemano, Saludos.

Comment: Estas retornando de la función principal en la linea que pones `return service;` antes que las funciones que la siguen se definan. Comienza por arreglar eso.

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, pero si quito el return services; el servicio deja de funcionar y me manda un error en la consola y no carga la pagina. o estoy entendiendo mal, incluso lo puse al final de las funciones y el sigue enviando undefined.

Comment: Lo de que te retorne la función del servicio `undefined` es porque `$http.get` realiza una tarea asíncrona. Posiblemente estas tratando de acceder a ella antes de que la respuesta del servidor llegue al cliente.

Comment: Por otro lado, trata de cerciorarte que respuesta recibes del servidor inspeccionando la llamada usando Google Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: Gracias, no soy muy experimentado con Google chrome dev tools, uso bastante la consola para probar, aunque creo que es lo que dices porque si pongo un console.log(), el la funcion http.get de getProfile, en la consola al rato de cargarme la siguiente vista, me imprime ya el resultado, pero después, en ese caso que tengo que hacer? que tengo que modificar, disculpa no soy muy experimentado. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Al presionar **`Ctrl+Shift+i`** se abre la herramienta y en la pestaña Network puedes ver las llamadas que salieron y que respuestas obtuvieron dichas llamadas. Mira [documentación](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network)

Comment: Lastimosamente no consigo abrir una sesión de chat contigo.

Comment: si, soy reciente en stackoverflow, revisare en la pestania de network como dices, pero es eso que dices, la funcion devuelve undefined primero, y hasta despues obtiene la respuesta del servidor, prueba de ello el console.log() que se ejecuta despues de del llamado de la funcion. talvez se me ocurre algo revisando bien en network. gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu servicio está mal diseñado. Todas las peticiones que haces les falta `return $http....` el lugar de simplemente invocar `$http`

Por ejemplo

```
function Profile(){
    return $http.get(apiURL + 'api/user/' + $localStorage.currentUser.id + '/').then(function successCallback(response) {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        console.log(response.data)
    });
 }

 function GetProfile(id){
    return $http.get(apiURL + 'api/user/' + id + '/').then(function successCallback(response){
        $rootScope.userProfile = response.data.Kind;
        localStorage.setItem('profile', $rootScope.userProfile);
        return $rootScope.userProfile;
     });     
}
```

Luego cuando quieres llamarlo haces esto

```
AuthenticationService.getProfile().then(function(profile) {
    console.log(profile);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Básicamente devuelves una promesa para encadenar que revisas una vez que la información te ha llegado del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas, tenes un problema de devolución, el segundo llamado en realidad te devuelve el valor del primero, que ya esta storeado.

Deberias hacer lo siguiente

```
function GetProfile(id){
    $http.get(apiURL + 'api/user/' + id + '/').
    then(function successCallback(response){
      $rootScope.userProfile = response.data.Kind;
      localStorage.setItem('profile', $rootScope.userProfile);
      return $rootScope.userProfile;
    });     

  }
```

La devolución del contenido la estas haciendo por fuera del get, por lo tanto lo que hace es primer hacer el llamado (que es async) y entregar el resultado que esta storeado... 
Si vos lo cambias por el código que menciono arriba, la función no va a devolver nada hasta que el get haya sido resuelto.
Saludos